# How can I export a function in C++ using #pragma comment(linker, "/export:...) when the path contains a special character and spaces in it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to create an export by doing the following:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:Breakpad_SetSteamID=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\crashhandler64.dll.Breakpad_SetSteamID,@1")
```

But I get the error:

```
1>dllmain.obj : fatal error LNK1276: invalid directive 'Files' found; does not start with '/'
```

Because the path contains spaces and (x86) in it.  How can I achieve this?

For example, when I do this:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:WldpIsAppApprovedByPolicy=C:\\Windows\\System32\\wldp.dll.WldpIsAppApprovedByPolicy,@1")
```

I get no errors, because the path is readable.

I've been trying to google an answer to this but I cannot find anything.

Thank you!

Edit: Answered in the comments.

For those of you who downvoted my question or questioned why I am using #pragma for this - the answer is ease of use.  It's for DLL proxying.

Comment: Why are you using `#pragma` for this? What's wrong with using either `__export`, `__declspec(dllexport)`, or a `.def` file? Those are the typical ways to export something.

Comment: This is just my preference.  I've found the solution anyway, I'll edit the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:Breakpad_SetSteamID=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\crashhandler64.dll.Breakpad_SetSteamID\",@1")
```